# Removing gap between two svg elements

Tags: html, css, svg

Two svg elements a `line` and `path` are rendered vertically. There is a gap between these two elements, which I would like to get rid of, but I don't know how.

```css
#upload-line-join {
  position: relative;
  left: 47px;
}

.svg-lines-wrapper {
  width: 97px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-lines-wrapper">
  <svg id="upload-play-vert-line" width="97" height="60">
    <line
      id="vert-line-1"
      x1="49.4"
      y1="0"
      x2="49.4"
      y2="60"
      stroke="#7e7e7e"
      stroke-width="2"
    />
  </svg>
  <svg id="upload-line-join" fill="none" height="15" width="15" viewBox="-1.3 0 15 15">
    <path
      id="vert-line-2"
      d="M 11, 10 C 5, 10, 1, 6, 1, 0"
      stroke="#7e7e7e"
      stroke-width="2"
    />
  </svg>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5rtmco22/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is white spaces so you can simply add `font-size:0` like this :

```css
#upload-line-join {
  position: relative;
  left: 47px;
}

.svg-lines-wrapper {
  width: 97px;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-lines-wrapper">
  <svg id="upload-play-vert-line" width="97" height="60">
                  <line
                    id="vert-line-1"
                    x1="49.4"
                    y1="0"
                    x2="49.4"
                    y2="60"
                    stroke="#7e7e7e"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  />
                </svg>
  <svg id="upload-line-join" fill="none" height="15" width="15" viewBox="-1.3 0 15 15">
                  <path
                    id="vert-line-2"
                    d="M 11, 10 C 5, 10, 1, 6, 1, 0"
                    stroke="#7e7e7e"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  />
                </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the `position` and `top` properties:

```css
#upload-line-join {
  position: relative;
  left: 47px;
}

.svg-lines-wrapper {
  width: 97px;
}

.svg-lines-wrapper > svg:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: -5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-lines-wrapper">
                <svg id="upload-play-vert-line" width="97" height="60">
                  <line
                    id="vert-line-1"
                    x1="49.4"
                    y1="0"
                    x2="49.4"
                    y2="60"
                    stroke="#7e7e7e"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  />
                </svg>
                <svg id="upload-line-join" fill="none" height="15" width="15" viewBox="-1.3 0 15 15">
                  <path
                    id="vert-line-2"
                    d="M 11, 10 C 5, 10, 1, 6, 1, 0"
                    stroke="#7e7e7e"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  />
                </svg>
              </div>
```

Comment: Right, I don't understand why Chrome inspector doesn't allow me to add top attributes for svg elements.

Answer (score 2):

SVG are like img, inline-block boxes, you just need here to reset vertical-align to avoid that gap.

```css
#upload-line-join {
  position: relative;
  left: 47px;
}

.svg-lines-wrapper {
  width: 97px;
}
svg {vertical-align:top;}
```

```html
<div class="svg-lines-wrapper">
  <svg id="upload-play-vert-line" width="97" height="60">
                  <line
                    id="vert-line-1"
                    x1="49.4"
                    y1="0"
                    x2="49.4"
                    y2="60"
                    stroke="#7e7e7e"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  />
                </svg>
  <svg id="upload-line-join" fill="none" height="15" width="15" viewBox="-1.3 0 15 15">
                  <path
                    id="vert-line-2"
                    d="M 11, 10 C 5, 10, 1, 6, 1, 0"
                    stroke="#7e7e7e"
                    stroke-width="2"
                  />
                </svg>
</div>
```